# Representing beauty contest with $n$ players in normal form game

Tags: contest-math, game-theory

I have a beauty contest question in which players must guess a number between $0$ and $5$. The closest score to ($p\times\text{average score}$) wins. Winners take 1 and losers take 0, whilst players who tie will both win. I have to represent this game in normal form, does anyone know how to do this for more than $2$ players, i.e for $n$ players?

Thanks all.

Comment: What do you mean by 'represent [...] in normal form'?

Comment: Do you mean: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal-form_game?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I should have specified. As you suggested, I am trying to represent the game in matrix form. Whilst trivial for 2 player games, I’m not sure about more players.

Comment: In win-lose games the payoffs are typically taken to be +1 to a wnner and 0 or -1 to a loser.   If ties are possible (as they are in this game,  when two or players make the same closest guess to the scaled average score), you need to decide what payoff the tied contestants wll receive.   So what are the payoffs for a win, loss and tie in this game?

Comment: Hi, in this instance, it is assumed winners take 1 and losers take 0. In a tie, both people would take 1. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $\ g_i\ $ is the guess made by player $\ i\ $, for $\ i=1,2,\dots, n\ $, the payoff, $\ P_j\left(g_1, g_2, \dots, g_n\right)\ $, to player $\ j\ $ is given by

$P_j\left(g_1, g_2, \dots, g_n\right)$
$$= H\left(\min_{1\le i\le n}\left(\left\vert\, g_i -\frac{p\sum_{k=1}^n g_k}{n}\right\vert\right)-\left\vert\, g_j -\frac{p\sum_{k=1}^n g_k}{n}\right\vert\right)\ ,\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 
$$
where 
$\ H\ $ is the [Heaviside step function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function), defined by
$$H\left(x\right) =\left\{ \begin{matrix} 0 & \mbox{ if } x < 0\ \ \\
1 & \mbox{ if } x \ge 0\ \ .
\end{matrix}\right.
 $$

Comment: great answer! in "p* sum(gk)" - what does "p" represent? thank you!

Comment: It's the same $\ p\ $ that appears in the second sentence of the question.